# How to get a random subreddit using praw and python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reddit, praw

I've tried googling and all I could find was how to get a random submission from a specific subreddit, but not a random subreddit. I remember reading about it weeks ago on some website but for the life of me I cannot find out where it was.

Comment: Please show some things you've tried, what you've found and put more effort into the question.

Answer (score 3):

> `random_subreddit(nsfw=False)`
>
> > Return a random lazy instance of `Subreddit`.
> >
> > Parameters: nsfw – Return a random NSFW (not safe for work) subreddit
> >     (default: False).

Checkout the docs [here](http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/reddit_instance.html#praw.Reddit.random_subreddit). Look at the `random_subreddit()` method.